# Partition a non partitioned container in azure cosmos db without any downtime

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a non partitioned container in azure cosmos DB, which has a size of 5.9 GB. I want to make this container partitioned using one of its fields. Since this container is being used in the live application, I don't want any downtime for the migration of partitioning. How can I achieve this?

The traditional way of spinning new container, make it partitioned and then migrate the data will not work because this will need some down time. I also read that Azure deprecated some scripts which were used to do this partitioning without any down time.

Comment: Could you please share what you tried with? It will be more understandable if you provide with some more details.

Comment: I'm still exploring the documents from Microsoft. Haven't tried anything yet. Not able to find any good document on this.

Comment: You can't change an existing container's partitioning; you have to create a new container and migrate your data. There is no magic "avoid downtime" solution, aside from your app continuing to rely on your existing container until your data migration task completes (should be fairly quick given the relatively small container size). There is plenty of documentation published around data migration. There are probably app-specific things you can do to mitigate downtime (caching maybe? read-only mode on your app?). This is a fairly broad question though with no single correct answer.